# Compilation failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a workflow in VS 2010, SharePoint 2010, Windows Server 2008 R2 environment. I added a sequential workflow to the application. When I was trying to build the application, it was throwing the below error because of the workflow.

> Compilation failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>   Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I tried all the solutions given in this site but no use.

Please help.

Comment: What are the contents of the LoaderExceptions property?

Comment: It might helpful to provide more details.

Comment: @Nanhydrin: How to view the contents of the LoaderExceptions property.

Comment: @Anthony: I created a new application and added a 'Sequential Workflow'. After adding the workflow, I tried to build the application. It is throwing this error. Let me know if I have to share any other information.

Comment: Actually if it's a compiler error I'm not sure how you'd get at the loader exceptions. You could try running it in Debug and setting the debug exceptions to break when the actual exception (whatever it is) is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to help diagnose this.

Firstly check that your projects are set to compile against the right version of the .NET framework. If your project dll references are using an older version of .NET but you're compiling against a newer one that could cause problems.

Next you should use the [Assembly Binding log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.90).aspx) (also known as Fuslogvw) to record exactly what dlls are failing to load and where they're being looked for as it may just be that one of them isn't in the right place but it should give you more information on why it can't be loaded.

Also, if you're referencing a x64 dll on an x86 system, or vice versa that would also cause a similar error, but the Assembly Binding log viewer should highlight those sorts of problems.

Comment: Microsoft.Sharepoint.Search dll is creating the problem. I removed the reference for this dll then it started working fine. Thank you for your help.